# cannot install shinyURL package from github

Tags: r, shiny, package

```
library(devtools)
> install_github("aoles/shinyURL")
Downloading GitHub repo aoles/shinyURL@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/aoles/shinyURL/zipball/master
Installing shinyURL
Installing 1 package: shiny
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/shiny_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2756653 bytes (2.6 MB)
downloaded 2.6 MB

package ‘shiny’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgH5Frh\downloaded_packages
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/bin/i386/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgH5Frh/devtools132036314e4d/aoles-shinyURL-ac5b683"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'shinyURL' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'bitops'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'shinyURL'
* removing 'C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/shinyURL'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Comment: try installing bitops first